# crm dynamics 2011 displaying multiple contacts in the crm application using addressable views

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I am using On-Premise crm dynamics 2011 and I am facing problem in the following situation. The requirement in one of the modules I am developing is to get an input from the end user and use it to filter the contacts in crm and display it to the user. I was doing this by using asp.net and crm sdk and I was retrieving the entity collection filtered by the user input and displaying the resultant contacts in a web page (custom aspx page outside crm). However, now the requirement is to display the contacts list within crm itself. Not in my asp.net application.

I was actually doing a similar thing of displaying a contact, by using the filter and fetching the guid of the contact and using the url

```
(http://server/organization/sfa/conts/edit.aspx?id=12b3bd97-57f8-e211-b4fd-000c29ea65f3).
```

This is fine with displaying a single contact. I was displaying all the contacts using the url

```
(http://server/organization/main.aspx?etc=2&etn=contact&extraqs=%3fpagemode%3diframe%26sitemappath%3dWorkplace%257cCustomers%257cnav_conts&pagetype=entitylist&viewid=%7b00000000-0000-0000-00AA-000010001004%7d&viewtype=1039).
```

Now the question is how can I open a similar form that displays only filtered contacts? Is there an in built form to fulfill my requirement? if not what I should do. I thought of creating a custom page and embedding in crm, however is it advisable in practical situations? I have this doubt because  I would be installing this customization to the client servers. Therefore there is a chance that they might not allow third party customizations. I was wondering if there was any other way to do it.

An example is, when a customer calls, I use his phone number as a filter to lookup for a contact in crm and if there are many contacts associated with the number I need to display them all to the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would build a custom html page.
Query the results using the OData service and display the results in a grid.
You can then add this webpage to a form or a dashboard using an IFRAME.

I've used a combination of crmfetchkit and jQGrid to implement this in the past.

http://crmfetchkit.codeplex.com/ 
http://www.trirand.com/blog/

Implementation is 100 percent client side javascript and works pretty well.

Comment: Could you please direct how I should add the custom web page in an IFrame in a way that I can access this from external applications using an URL, for eg: we can use the contact form using the url (http://server/organization/sfa/conts/edit.aspx?id=12b3bd97-57f8-e211-b4fd-000c29ea65f3)

Comment: Once you've added the HTML page as a webresource you can use the webresource link to access it from anywhere. You'll need to be logged in to CRM of course for this to work.